# pass data back from static library view controller to applications Appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I am creating a a small library with just a login screen(MyViewController), in objective c.This screen should take a passcode and send it back to the application using the library.

```
@implementation MyViewController
  - (id)init {
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyLibraryResources" withExtension:@"bundle"]];

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:bundle];

if ((self = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nav"])) {
}
    count=0;


return self;
}
```

Now i make this login screen as a root view controller in my application appdelegate which is implementing the library.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
  }
```

I am not sure how can i send data/passcode back from my library view controller to application appdelegate.

Any help or tutorial will be of great help.

Comment: You can use a delegation pattern or pass a block to be invoked.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11,thanks for ur suggestion.it worked for me. However i was initializing MyViewController with navigation controller which was having my viewcontroller, now if i use delegate i have to initialize using viewcontroller directly and i loose navigation controller. Is there any way to use / embed navigation controller. if ((self = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nav"], here nav is navigation controller

Comment: You can simply access your view controller instance from the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array